# stop jquery toggling when referenced div is clicked

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery and there is probably another function that i should be using to achieve this so please tell me.

I have a drop down box that is dropped down with a toggle but when the drop down box is clicked it fades out. This cannot happen as there are links inside the drop down.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K3GpR/1/) so please have a look and see what i'm doing wrong.

HTML:

```
<span id="profile">
        <span id="profileDrop">
          <div id="triangleUp"></div>
          <div id="profileDown">
           <a href="../likes.php"><div id="profileElement"><img src="files/images/heart.png" height="12px" border="0"><d> Your Favourites</d></div></a>
           <a href="../tracks.php"><div id="profileElement"><img src="files/images/settings.png" height="12px" border="0"><d> Settings</d></div></a>
           <a href="../phpscripts/logout.php"><div id="profileElement"><img src="files/images/logout.png" height="12px" border="0" /><d> Logout</d></div></a>
          </div>  
        </span>
      </span>​
```

jQuery:

```
$('#profile').toggle(function(){

        $('#profileDown', '#profile').fadeIn(300);
        $('#triangleUp', '#profile').fadeIn(300);
    }, function(){

        $('#profileDown', this).fadeOut(300);
        $('#triangleUp', '#profile').fadeOut(300);
});​
```

Comment: Your markup looks somehow problematic... `div` inside nested `spans`? `<d>`?

Comment: @elclanrs you're right it does look weird. @Jacob Windsor, you might benefirt from using `<div>` tags rather than spans.

Comment: Also please place relevant code in the post, jsfiddle links tend to break over time.

Comment: Notes noted, thanks very much. I hadn't validated it but have now. It worked so i took no notice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding:

```
$('#profile a').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});​
```

This will stop the click event from propagating up from your links and triggering the fade.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/K3GpR/3/)**

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much, i'll accept your answer in 11 minutes apparently

Answer (score 0):

Because it's inside the `#profile` element so it's bubbling up to the parent element and toggling and eventually fading.

Try

```
    $('#profile').toggle(function(){
        $('#profileDown', '#profile').fadeIn(300);
        $('#triangleUp', '#profile').fadeIn(300);
        return false;
    }, function(){

        $('#profileDown', this).fadeOut(300);
        $('#triangleUp', '#profile').fadeOut(300);
        return false;
    });​
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for, but does this http://jsfiddle.net/K3GpR/5/ achieve what you are looking for?

Basically what I did was pulled your drop down menu out of the span that you attach your toggle to.

```
<span id="profile">
   <span id="profileDrop">
       <div id="triangleUp"></div>
   </span>
</span>
<div id="profileDown">
     <a href="../likes.php"><div id="profileElement"><img src="files/images/heart.png" height="12px" border="0">Your Favourites</div></a>
     <a href="../tracks.php"><div id="profileElement"><img src="files/images/settings.png" height="12px" border="0">Settings</div></a>
     <a href="../phpscripts/logout.php"><div id="profileElement"><img src="files/images/logout.png" height="12px" border="0" />Logout</div></a>
</div> ​
```

This nesting was causing your toggle event to fire even when the drop menu was clicked on. Now just the image triggers the toggle. (I also changed your selectors a little. Just personal preference).

Here is the updated js:

```
$('#profile').toggle(function(){

        $('#profileDown').fadeIn(300);
        $('#triangleUp').fadeIn(300);
    }, function(){

        $('#profileDown').fadeOut(300);
        $('#triangleUp').fadeOut(300);

    });​
```